# The method get(int) in the type List<String> is not applicable for the argument string in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, predicate

I'm trying to search for an element in a `List<String>` and I get this compilation error:

> the method `get(int)` in the type `List<String>` is not applicable for the argument string.

This is the code:

```
private boolean findIdInTheList(List<String> ids, String id) {
    String theId = ids.stream()
            .filter(elem -> id.equals(ids.get(elem)))
            .findAny()
            .orElse(null);
}
```

Comment: btw your method makes little sense, you want to *find* the id, but return a `boolean`; then even if you correct this you return a `null` to denote a missing value, but what if `null` is part of the List (bad idea to begin with yes, but what if) - it would be much more appropriate to return an `Optional` or even better to use `anyMatch`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ids` is a `List<String>` and `elem` is a `String`. Therefore `ids.get(elem)` is invalid, since `List` has no `get` method that takes a `String`.

It should be:

```
private boolean findIdInTheList(List<String> ids, String id) {
    String theId = ids.stream()
                      .filter(elem -> id.equals(elem))
                      .findAny()
                      .orElse(null);
}
```

Oh, and since your method has a `boolean` return type, you should add a return statement.

You can simplify the pipeline with `anyMatch`:

```
private boolean findIdInTheList(List<String> ids, String id) {
    return ids.stream()
              .anyMatch(elem -> id.equals(elem));
}
```

Here you get a `boolean` that indicates whether `id` was found in the `List`. I see no point in returning the `String` itself, since you already know that it's equal to `id`.

Comment: Thank you Eran! If I want to add the id in the ids list if the id is not find what should I do. The method could have return type void.

Comment: @gaby you can write `if (!ids.stream().anyMatch(elem -> id.equals(elem))) {ids.add(id);}`, though I wouldn't use `Stream`s for that. Just do `if (ids.indexOf(id)<0) ids.add(id);`

Comment: @Eran or just `if( ! ids.contains(id)) ids.add(id);`… And I think, it’s worth mentioning in the answer that this is a Stream overuse.

Comment: @Holger true. I'm not used to thinking of `contains()` method in the context of `List` interface, even though it is declared in the base `Collection` interface.

Answer (score 2):

```
.filter(elem -> id.equals(elem))
```

you already have the `elem` from the source in this `Predicate`

You can also write it as a method reference:

```
.filter(id::equals)
```

Answer (score 0):

`.filter(elem -> id.equals(ids.get(elem)))` is wrong here, You have already done `ids.stream()` which means `ids`(all elements of **ids**) are already converted into stream and are present to pass or fail through `filter()`.

Now you are applying a `filter()` which is a predicate and will return bool(true or false).

Now you just need to compare your string element with stream value, you don't need to again get into List by doing `get()`.

---

For sake of more understanding with different approach:

```
List<String> ids = Arrays.asList("Vishwa","Eran","Eugene","gaby","nullpointer");
String id = "gaby";
Predicate<String> pre = (p1)->p1.equals("gaby");
String theID = ids.stream().filter(s->pre.test(id)).findAny().orElse(null);
```

*What above users(Eran and Eugene) have said are absolutely correct,I inclined with them, I just wanted to add more clear explanation with what i understand.*